# Check if Hadoop cluster exists

Tags: python, hadoop, cgi

I'm building a Python CGI based website that lets me setup a Hadoop cluster.
I was wondering if there was any way to check if there's already a premade cluster present? Because I want to limit the website to creating only one cluster at a time. I want to know if an **offline** cluster exists.

The only idea I have so far, is to save a flag into a file when the cluster is made and change its value when the cluster is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Aditya - Make sure that your Hadoop ports are listening in the machine. In default hdfs run under the port 9000, Similarly you can fix a default ports for hadoop and filter it out as per your requirement.

Make a unique identification over the HDFS metadata directory. or list the hadoop conf file (core-site,hdfs-site....) in each directory. These are the mandatory things for hadoop.

You can able to get it in Environmental variables/Classpath, or use this command `hadoop version`. It will works when path variables(%HADOOP_HOME%) properly configured.It doesn't requires any hadoop services are in running state rather proper environmental variable are configured in that machine.